# Accessing script file location from an external file python

Tags: python, inheritance, path, filepath

I have the following bizarre set up. Consider 3 scripts in different directories:

- root1/folderA/scriptA.py
- root2/folderB/scriptB.py
- root2/folderC/scriptC.py

The first file and it's location are fully modifiable. The second and third are completely fixed.

scriptA.py contains a parent class:

```
class A:
    def get_path(self):
        # ...
        # code to determine "my_path"
        # ...
        return my_path
```

scriptB.py contains a child class:

```
from root1.folderA.scriptA import A

class B(A):
    pass
```

scriptC.py contains the code to execute:

```
from root2.folderB.scriptB import B

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    print(b.get_path()) # want print root/folderB/scriptB.py
```

In scriptC.py what I want is the behaviour to get the path of the child class's declaration file (without any hard-coding). Is there any way to program the `A.get_path()` to have this behavoir?

I've tried looking into the `inspect`, `os.path` and `pathlib` modules but I haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the trick is to use `__init_subclass__` which runs whenever a class is sub-classed, in conjunction with a class's `__module__` attribute to retrieve its containing module, and `__file__` to retrieve the absolute path to the python script or module.

For example, in `script_a.py`:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path


class PathInfo:
    __slots__ = ()

    path: Path

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        mod = sys.modules[cls.__module__]
        # `__file__` is a string, so we want to convert to a `Path` so it's easier to work with
        cls.path = Path(mod.__file__)


class A(PathInfo):
    __slots__ = ()
```

`script_b.py`:

```
from script_a import A


class B(A):
    pass


# prints: /Users/<name>/PycharmProjects/my-project/script_a.py
print(A().path)
# prints: /Users/<name>/PycharmProjects/my-project/script_b.py
print(B.path)
```

Comment: Did you check this? I had the same idea with `__file__`, just without the `Path` and `cached_property` and my `B` prints the file of `A`, which is a bit surprising tbh.

Comment: Yep, I just checked this, and was surprised too. I think what's happening is that `__file__` is calculated at compile time, and evaluates to whichever script you're calling it from. I updated my code though, so the new version appears to at least work as expected.

Comment: That was my solution too but according to the question, the B script can't be changed I believe

Comment: @LukasNeugebauer I see, I did some quick tests and was able to simplify my code greatly. See my updated answer above :-)

Comment: Thanks so much that works a treat! Ngl it's black magic to me but I'll look into it to see if I can better understand what's going on.

Comment: Yeah, it actually kind of does look like magic to me now :-) The lines with `__slots__` can be removed if it detracts from the understanding, but the rest should be mostly straightforward hopefully.

Comment: @rv.kvetch That did help thanks! I also got a slightly more minimal version up and running without the need for the additional `PathInfo` class: `class A:

    path = Path(__file__)

    def __init_subclass__(cls):
        mod = sys.modules[cls.__module__]
        cls.path = Path(mod.__file__)`